# Using withState and lifecycle from recompose together

Tags: reactjs, recompose

I would like to build a component that randomly updates numeric props to  different positions on a chessboard.

In order to do this, I created a simple component with an interval:

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/ezxnjc8h/

```
export default class RandomPosition extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.interval = null;
        this.state = {
            x: 0,
            y: 0
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.interval = setInterval(() => {
            this.setState({
                x: Math.floor(Math.random() * 8),
                y: Math.floor(Math.random() * 8)
            })
        }, 500)
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.interval)
    }

    render() {
        return <Test knightPosition={[this.state.x, this.state.y]} moveKnight={this.props.moveKnight} />
    }
}
```

I am interested in converting the same to a Hoc using the recompose library using `withState` and `lifecycle` to do so.

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/kzwc9yha/

```
export default compose(
    withState('knightPosition', 'moveKnight', [1,7]),
    lifecycle({
        componentDidMount() {
           this.interval = setInterval(() => {
               this.props.moveKnight[Math.floor(Math.random() * 8), Math.floor(Math.random() * 8)]
            }, 500)
        },
        componentWillUnmount() {
            clearInterval(this.interval)
        }
    })
)(Test)
```

Comment: could you please specify the issue that you are facing

Comment: Iam sorry, to me this looks like you are asking someone else to write it for you, can you try explain what did you try? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues in your fiddle.

First: You haven't imported `lifecycle` from `Recompose`

Second: `moveKnight` is a function and hence it needs to be invoked like

```
 this.interval = setInterval(() => {
         this.props.moveKnight(
             [Math.floor(Math.random() * 8), Math.floor(Math.random() * 8)]
         );
    }, 500)
```

**[Working DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/75a9exnp/6/)**